# CSS menu alignment issue - novice developer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Am a novice developer and really need some assistance in trying to get my websites topicmenu section to align widthwise with the above maroon newsbar section above it.  It might be simple solution but myself as a newbie is really finding it tough.  You can see the code via jsbin url below which gives the code and output:

```css
    body{
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#topbar{
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 color: black;
}

.fixedwidth{
 width: 1050px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#logodiv{
 padding-top: 5px;
 float: left;
 border-right: 1px solid;
 padding-right: 10px;
}

#signindiv{
 padding-top: 5px 80px 10px 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 width: 200px;
 float: left;
 border-right: 1px solid;
}

#signindiv img{
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
}

#topmenudiv{
 float: left;
}

#topmenudiv ul{
 margin-top: 10px;
 padding: 0;
}

#topmenudiv li{
 list-style: none;    /* removes bullet points, numbers etc */
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 border-right: 1px solid;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 7px 20px 0px 20px;
 display: inline; /* makes the list appear horizontal*/
}

#searchdiv{
 float: left;
 padding: 5px 0 0 10px;
}

#searchdiv input{
 height: 15px;
 padding: 1px;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

.break{
 clear: both;
}

#newsbar{
 background-color: #BB1919;
 width: 100%;
 height: 101px;
 color: white;
}

#newsbar p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 padding-top: 10px;
}

#newsheader {
 font-size: 3em;
}

#UK {
 font-size: 0.5em;
 
}

#rss{
 float: right;
 margin-top: -30px;
}

#topicmenu{
 width: 100%;
}

#topicmenu ul {
 background-color: #A91717;
 padding: 0;
 menu: 0;
 height: 20px;
 
}

#topicmenu li{
 list-style: none;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 padding: 5px;
 border-right: 1px solid right;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>BBC Homepage</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="topbar">
            
            <div class="fixedwidth">
                <div id="logodiv">
                    <img src="images/bbclogo.png"/>
                </div>
                <div id="signindiv">
                    <img src="images/signin.png"/> Sign In
                    
                    
                
                </div>
            
            </div>
            
            <div id="topmenudiv">
                        <ul>
                            <li> News </li>
                            <li> Sport </li>
                            <li> Weather </li>
                            <li> Shop </li>
                            <li> Earth </li>
                            <li> Travel </li>
                            <li> More... </li>
                        </ul>
                    
                    </div>
            
            <div id="searchdiv">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="break"> </div>
        
        <div id="newsbar">
            
            <div class="fixedwidth">
                <p id="newsheader"> NEWS <span id="UK">UK</span> </p>
                
                <div id="rss">
                 RSS
                </div>
                
                <div class="break"> </div>
                
                <div id="topicmenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Home</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>    
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/zufilusudi/edit?html,output

Any advice or assistance that you can give to me will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following order of elements:

```
<div id="newsbar">
            <div class="fixedwidth">
                <p id="newsheader"> NEWS <span id="UK">UK</span> </p>
                <div id="rss">
                 RSS
                </div>
                <div class="break"> </div>
            </div>                
             <div id="topicmenu">
                 <div class="fixedwidth">
                   <ul>
                     <li>Home</li>
                  </ul>
             </div>
           </div>
    </div>
```

This moves the #topicmenu out of the .fixedwidth DIV (allowing it to span the whole width), but puts the contents of it in another .fixedwidth DIV, lining up the contents with the contents of the elements above

Comment: thanks, i shall give this a try and give my feedback

Answer (score 1):

Your elements Are the same size, the red background is from the parent element #newsbar, not from the #newsheader element.

Here's where the confusion comes from:

Your bottom element that seems to be of different size is actually overflowing from the parent element, so it doesn't have the same background anymore because it's displaying outside of #newsbar

Set height:auto on #newsbar and you'll have a visual of what's going on, then you can adjust the code accordingly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your `#newsbar`has `height: 101px`

If you just erase this heigth setting or set it to "auto" , the topicmenu lines up with it at the bottom.

Comment: thanks for your response buddy but there seems to be no change at all.  Basically what I need is for the topicmenu colour bar and newsbars width to be matching.  right now topicmenu seems to be of different widths even when I am setting width of both to be the same.

Comment: ah, the width - soory, I thought you were concerned about the vertical alignment. The reason for the width difference is, that "newsbar" is inside a DIV that has class "fixedwith" with a width setting of 1050px. You could move the "#newsbar" DIV outside of the "fixedwidth" DIV, but then also the text will move all the way to the left, but - well I better write another answer to show the code I mean.